# How to get bitmap from uri if data.getData()==null?

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

Here `data` is of the type `Intent` and `data.getData()==null` so i tried getting uri using

```
Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(index).getUri();  //data.getClipData()!=null
```

Now how do i get a bitmap from this imageUri?

Using the below code

`Bitmap bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this,imageUri)` gives an EXCEPTION error

Comment: exception? what exception? whats the `Uri`'s exact value and what stacktrace did you get?

Comment: Path: /document/primary:1.jpg

Comment: E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/primary:1.jpg (No such file or directory)

Comment: I had put a Log to check the value of Path returned, Log.i("Path",imageUri.getPath());

Comment: `Log.i(TAG,"uri: " + imageUri);` what is the value of `Uri`? and what do you need a `Bitmap` for?

Comment: uri: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3A1.jpg

Comment: good, and what do you need a `Bitmp` for? cannot you just use that `Uri` directly?

Comment: I had to create an application in which the main activity had a button which on clicking took the user to the gallery where he selected the images and the selected images got displayed on the initial activity. I have got the uri of all the selected images but i cant figure out how should i display the images now

Comment: `ImageView.setImageURI()`

Comment: THANK YOU SOO MUCH FOR THE HELP. This really worked. Is there any way i can make the image views dynamic? As in i have created 4 image views before hand and If the user makes upto 4 selections then i have no problem to set the uri of individual image views to the selected uri. However if the user selects more than 4 images, say 8-10 then is there any way to add the image views dynamically , based on the user's selection

Comment: use `RecyclerView` in such cases

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3788176)